# doPostBack not firing

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, dom-events, dopostback

I'm following the next project: http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-context-menu-item-with-custom-code

ELEMENTS.XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
     <CustomAction Id="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.ButtonClicked"
             RegistrationType="FileType"
            RegistrationId="dtsx"
            Location="EditControlBlock"
            ImageUrl="/_layouts/IMAGES/DOCLINK.GIF"
            Sequence="600"
            Title="Execute Package"
            Description="Executed Selected Package"
            ControlAssembly="SPTest.CustomMenuItem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=beb14bc625e99e7f"
            ControlClass="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.CustomItemAction"
            >
<UrlAction Url="javascript:__doPostBack('SPTest.CustomMenuItem.CustomItemAction',  {ItemId});" />
</CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

PACKAGE.TEMPLATE.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Assemblies>
  <Assembly Location="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.dll"  DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
    <SafeControls>
      <SafeControl Assembly="SPTest.CustomMenuItem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=beb14bc625e99e7f" 
                 Namespace="SPTest.CustomMenuItem" TypeName="*" Safe="True"        SafeAgainstScript="False" />
    </SafeControls>
  </Assembly>
</Assemblies>
</Solution>
```

So... In Web.config file we can find our assembly in SafeControl

CLASS TO EXECUTE

```
   using System.IO;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using Microsoft.SharePoint;
   using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

    namespace SPTest.CustomMenuItem
    {
        public class CustomItemAction : SPLinkButton
        {
            protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {
                this.EnsureChildControls();
                base.OnLoad(e);
                if (this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] ==   "SPTest.CustomMenuItem.ButtonClicked")
                {
                    int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(this.Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
                    System.IO.TextWriter writer = new  StreamWriter(@"C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\custommenuoutput.txt", true);
                    writer.WriteLine("Event Fired at:" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": Item ID:" + itemId.ToString());
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the objective is to execute a SSIS package that is allocate on Sharepoint. A ECB menu with Execute Package option appeared in all files that have dtsx type. Therefore when I clicked in this bottom, the event doesn't work... I don't know what I have to do... Any helped will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create separate action in SiteAction menu:

> <CustomAction Id="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.CustomActionsDispatcher" 
>   GroupId="SiteActions"   Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
>   Sequence="1000"   Title="Custom Actions Dispatcher"
>   ControlAssembly="SPTest.CustomMenuItem, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=beb14bc625e99e7f"
>   ControlClass="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.CustomItemAction">
>   </CustomAction>

The ECB menu is populated dynamically using async request, so on when page is posted, controls for ECB menu are not created and event for them are not fired. While Site actions controls are always rendered, so can handle postback.

Comment: I'm replace my code to yours and nothing happens... No option appears in SiteActions group

Comment: Option should not be visible in SiteActions group - it should be there but invisible. To make it visible you should provide Title for it. Does page get refreshed when choose your custom action (is it really posted)? If yes, try to add **protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)** to CustomItemAction and set breakpoint inside - if break point is not triggered on page refresh, then it means that CustomItemAction is not page control tree and can't handle postback.

Answer (score 0):

Revisit the page you are mentioning:

http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-context-menu-item-with-custom-code

His edit (16/02/2012) fixes this issue ("We also need to tell SharePoint to load the control"):

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Control ControlAssembly="SPTest.CustomMenuItem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={PublicKeyToken}"
ControlClass="SPTest.CustomMenuItem.CustomItemAction" Sequence="50" Id="AdditionalPageHead"/>
<CustomAction ...
```

You then can omit the attributes `ControlAssembly` and `ControlClass` in the `CustomAction` element. This is not done in his post, but mentioned in a comment (I tried it out and it works).

Please also note what other comments in his blog post say: "Drawback is that the control will load everywhere now so you have to make sure no other code, except the code you filter using the __EVENTTARGET fires." This is already implemented in his example, but still noteworty.